# Про лужу и калужу

Tags: этимология, лексика

Какова этимология этих слов и почему ***лужу*** называли также ***калужей***, что отразилось в названии города Кулуги?

Каково  значение корня  слова ***лужа*** (это и.-е корень)?

Есть ли у него исторические родственники в других языковых группах, кроме славянской?

И ***сесть в калошу*** — это действительно ***сесть в лужу***?